# Microsoft Servicebus fails to create QueueClient

Tags: .net, exception, azure-queues

I'm trying to create a `QueueClient` for my Azure ServiceBus Queue.

> var client = MessagingFactory.CreateQueueClient("testqueue");

I'm hitting this code using a breakpoint, but then after this, nothing happens. No exception but also no next step in code...

I'm using this inside another application so I think it might has to do something with assembly versions of somesort, but shouldn't this throw an exception? I'm very confused...

**edit:**

Nor the "No client" or the "Yes client" is written to the console. Also, no exception?!:

`var client = MessagingFactory.CreateQueueClient("testqueue");
if(client == null) {
   Console.WriteLine("No client");
} else {
   Console.WriteLine("Yes client");
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here, that receiveAndDelete means "Won't continue until a message has been received", so basically your program is waiting to receive a message from the queue.

Are you sure there is any messages in your testqueue?

You can't always trust the azure portal in this regard, so try adding a few more messages.

To Confirm, try waiting 1 minute (the default timeout). You should then get a TimeoutException, as explained here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh182019.aspx

Comment: I'm actually trying to send a message, not receive.. :)